# Type checkbox is not assignable to type number

Tags: typescript

I'm using `Inquirer.js` module in the TodoApp for prompting questions.
I'm facing the error `type checkbox is not assignable to type number`.

```
function promptComplete(): void{
    console.clear();
    inquirer.prompt({
        type: "checkbox",
        name: "complete",
        message: "Mark Task Complete",
        Choice:  collection.getTodoItems(showCompleted).map(item=>({name:item.task, value:item.id, checked:item.complete}))
        }).then(answers => {
            let completedTasks = answers["complete"] as number[];
            collection.getTodoItems(true).forEach(item => 
                collection.markCompleted(item.id, completedTasks.find(id => id===item.id) != undefined));
                promptUser();
        })
        
}
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem? It looks like I am learning from the same book .

Answer (score 0):

I found a mistake in your code:

in line 7 change "Choice" to "choices"

```
inquirer.prompt({ type: "checkbox", name: "complete",
        message: "Oznaczanie zadań jako wykonanych",
        choices: collection.getTodoItems(showCompleted).map(item => 
            ({name: item.task, value: item.id, checked: item.complete}))
    })
```